# Couldnt create log files batch-file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set _logs=serverdata\logs\
if not exist %_logs% MKDIR %_logs%
chcp 65001
color 0F
cls
:restart
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/." %%a in ("%DATE%") do (set _date=%%c-%%b-%%a)
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=,:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set _time=%%a%%b%%c)
server.exe -batchmode -datadir "serverdata/" -oxidedir "serverdata/oxide" -logfile "%_logs%output_%_date: =0%.%_time: =0%.txt"
timeout /T 5
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/." %%a in ("%DATE%") do (set _date=%%a-%%b-%%c)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=,:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set _time=%%a:%%b)
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo :: The server was restarted - %_date% %_time% ::
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto restart
```

Log doesn't create. Win 2008 R2. Try this: [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

maybe problem in quotes? But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in UAC settings.
Disabling them solved the problem.